# MVC Partial Views Validations

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, controllers

I have a question for a behaviour that I don't understand.
I have added some data annotation to my PartialClass, and created a partial view for it.
All works as expected if I use

```
 @Html.Partial("_partial", new PartialClass())
```

On my View. The problem is that if I try to get the same partial view from my controller, using

```
    public ActionResult GetNew()
    {
        return PartialView("_partial", new PartialClass());
    }
```

I don't get the same results, because the HTML that is render is different. Don't have any validation tags.

Can anyone help me to understand and to get the same HTML from my PartialView in my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use unobtrusive javascript and tell jQuery that it needs to include the newly loaded form' for validation

See my posting on this at:

[ASP.Net MVC: Can you use Data Annotations / Validation with an AJAX / jQuery call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825631/asp-net-mvc-can-you-use-data-annotations-validation-with-an-ajax-jquery-call)

Its probably because your FormContext doesn't exist when you call it via GetNew - the attributes aren't rendered out unless there is a FormContext