# MVC 3 Client side validation stop working after POST

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, client-side-validation

I've used a jQuery ajax post on a form generated from a MSAjax MVC 3 Razor view.

In this form the client side validation works correctly during typing but when the user generate a "POST" clicking on "Search" button the client side validation stop running!!

this is the model:

```
public class AnagraficaSearchViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(2)]
        public virtual string Ricerca { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(AnagraficaSearchViewModel model)
{
    if (model.Ricerca == "12")
    {
        model.Status = Status.Error;
        model.Message = "Errore!";

        ModelState.AddModelError("", Cult.Testo(Cult.CultTextsIDs.StatusError));                
    }

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) return PartialView("SearchCriteria", model);

    return View(model);
}
```

This is the main view:

```
<div id="search-anagrafica-criteria">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("SearchCriteria", Model); }
</div>
```

And this is the SearchCriteria View:

```
@model AnagraficaSearchViewModel

<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckRow() {
        $("form").valid();
        abs.message.convertErrorsToTooltips();
    };

    function InitSearch() {
        $("#Ricerca").bind("propertychange keyup input paste", function () {
            setTimeout("CheckRow();", 100);
        });

        CheckRow();

        $("#Ricerca").focus();
    }


    $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var $form = $(this);

            if (!$form.valid()) {
                abs.message.convertErrorsToTooltips();
                return false;
            }

            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));  //added

            if ($(this).valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#search-anagrafica-criteria').html(result);
                        InitSearch();
                    },
                    complete: function (result) {
                        CheckRow();
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });

        InitSearch();
    });

</script>

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Anagrafica", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "search-anagrafica-criteria", HttpMethod = "POST", OnComplete = "CheckRow()" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(el => el.Ricerca)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(el => el.Ricerca)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(el => el.Ricerca)

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="margin-left: 10px">Search</button>

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)    
}
```

Many hours of work and nothing changed!!

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you try removing $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form')); from the original place and place it after all your view code... that is, add the following code right before you close your AjaxForm parantesis...  <script type="text/javascript">
       $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));            
    </script>

Comment: Even if you moved its location, the parse method won't rebind the unobtrusive validation if you don't remove the data elements first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following instead:

```
      $('form').removeData("validator");
      $('form').removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
      $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
```

Comment: Your suggestion do not solve the problem. And your code add a <label class="error" for="Ricerca"> after the input.

Answer (score 1):

I use a slightly more 'advanced' way than just reparsing the form.
See my posting at:

[ASP.Net MVC: Can you use Data Annotations / Validation with an AJAX / jQuery call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825631/asp-net-mvc-can-you-use-data-annotations-validation-with-an-ajax-jquery-cal)

Comment: This is perfect form me! Thank you Adam!